# How to write and output file using command line arguments

Tags: c++, unix, command-line-arguments

I am trying to using command line arguments to pass a line of text into an output file. I know you can do this with an input file.
I am using unix to run a program and I compile it and run it like this:

```
g++ -o program program.C 
./program
```

So how would I run the program to write a line of text "Something like this" into an out.txt output file.

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file from inside the program, or how to [redirect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) output from it?

Comment: Hmm I would like to redirect output from it.

Comment: To redirect output from your program and create/overwrite `out.txt`, type into your shell `./program > out.txt`.  To append, type `./program >> out.txt`.  To capture standard error (`std::cerr`) output in `out.txt` too, try `./program 2>&1 > out.txt`.  You can read about these things in your shell man-page - e.g. type "ps" to see if your shell is `bash`, `ksh`, `tcsh`, `ash`, `zsh` etc., then `man bash` (or whatever) to read the man page.

Answer (score 1):

So if your command line looks like `./program <filename> <text_to_append>` the following would work:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv [])
{
    // first argument is program name
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        std::ofstream ofs;
        ofs.open (argv[1], std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);  
        ofs << argv[2];
        ofs.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```